# How to match the sentence that start with "أقول " by this code?

Tags: c#, regex

How to match the sentence that start with "أقول " by this code?

```
Regex.Matches(Content, "أقول " );
```

This is an arbic word. "أقول " 
What is the regular expression exactly ?

Comment: If you know the exact text you are looking for, why can't you just using something like `string.StartsWith()`?

Comment: @JonathanWood This isn't as trivial as it seems.  Arabic is a RTL language.  So do I reverse all the letters and use a regular regex? Even though arabic is RTL, are the characters stored LTR?  What does `StartsWith()` mean in the context of a RTL language?

Comment: We want to find all of the text that start with this and ended this

Comment: It makes no difference that the letters are RTL. My native language Hebrew is also RTL and regexes work just fine. Note that care must be taken to ensure that all strings are always stored and used as UTF-8, even in databases and network exchanges.

Comment: @dotancohen My question isn't merely if regexes work just fine, my question is what would a regex for the beginning of an RTL string look like?  For LTR, I'd use something like `/abcde*/`, does this mean I need to do `/*edcba/` for a RTL language?

Comment: @mj-gholami: So you want the text that starts with "أقول"  and ends with it? for example: "أقول ولكن لا أسمع ما أقول لأن صوتك عال", this should match: "أقول ولكن لا أسمع ما أقول", right?

Comment: Arabic is *rendered* RTL, but like the Latin alphabet (this one), the first logical character is stored first in memory, which can be thought of naïvely as LTR.

Comment: @TreyE: You don't need to pay any attention to the fact that the string is RTL. RTL is how the UA _displays_ the text, the bits making them up are still one-after-another. The UA knows the directionality of each character for display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding you comment, you want to find any match that starts with "أقول " and ends with "أقول". If this is true, then this is the way:

```
Regex.Matches(Content, "أقول .*أقول");
```

For example, if the `Content` is:

> أقول ولكنك لا تسمع ما أقول بسبب صوتك العالي

Then it will match:

> أقول ولكنك لا تسمع ما أقول

There is no problem with Arabic being RTL, it's all about viewing, they are not stored in in reverse!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a good candidate for me :

```
Regex.Matches(Content, @"أقول.*أقول");
```

Maybe it's help a bit : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/6d511f59-ae7c-46f5-9453-e4cb93ed6123 at the end of the page an anwser is available.

Comment: The `RightToLeft` option specifies that the search will be from Right to Left, it doesn't mean what direction the searched text is.